# Controller receives undefined on calling function from factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

The code contains two controllers `teacher` and `render`, the `teacher` controller sets value in factory `share` and `render` calls `get()` function from factory to receive value in `$scope.maincode` but `console.log($scope.maincode)` displays undefined. So,the HTML page does not render the `{{m.code}}` value. Below are the related snippets.

**controller-1**

```
app.controller("teacher",function($rootScope,$scope,$http,$location,$window,share){
    $scope.load = function(){
      $http.get('/getcode').success(function(data){
        if(data.length>0){
          $scope.message = "";
          $scope.codes = data;
          console.log($scope.codes);
        }
        else {
          $scope.codes="";
          $scope.message = "No code submissions yet";
        }
      })
      $scope.send = function(id){
        console.log(id);
        $http.get("/code/"+id).success(function(data){
          share.set(data);
          $window.location.href ='/code';
        })
      }
    });
```

**controller-2**

```
app.controller('render',function($rootScope,$scope,share){
  $scope.renders = function(){
    $scope.m=share.get();
    console.log($scope.m);
    }
  });
```

**factory**

```
app.factory('share',function(){
  var data = {};
  this.set = function(obj){
    this.data = obj;
    console.log(this.data);
  }
  this.get = function(){
    return this.data;
  }
  return {
    set: this.set,
    get: this.get
 }
```

});

**HTML File**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/" />
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="render">
    <div  data-ng-init="renders()">
      {{m.code}}
    </div>
    <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

**HTML File-2(which invokes teacher controller)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/" />
    <script src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div data-ng-controller="teacher">
      <div data-ng-init="load()">
        <div ng-repeat="code in codes" ng-show="codes">
          <a href ng-click="send(code.id)">{{code.title}}</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>{{message}}</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
  </body>
```

I googled regarding this issue, read the existing questions on similar issues, but couldn't find a solution.
Please help.

Comment: remove this from this.data inside set and get functions in factory or , do this.data = {}

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using two different pages, you either need to use some router, e.g. `ngRouter` or `ui-router`, or use `localStorage`. Here is the example of using `localStorage`:

```
app.factory('share', function () {
    function set(obj) {
        localStorage.setItem('share', obj);
    }

    function get() {
        return localStorage.getItem('share');
    }

    return {
        set: set,
        get: get
    }
});
```

Comment: $scope.$watch approach didn't work. HTML is not rendering `m.code`.

Comment: 'Provider 'share' must return a value from $get factory method.'

Comment: @RitikSaxena, put a `console.log(value)` before `$scope.m = value;`. What does it output?

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice you updated the factory, when I used the updated factory code, it says: share.on is not a function

Comment: let's continue in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126030/discussion-between-maximus-and-ritik-saxena).

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the result from the promise by the time you are displaying `render` and `m.code`.

To overcome this, just `broadcast` to the scope after you got the value from the get request in `teacher` controller.

```
`$rootScope.$broadcast('data-received');`
```

now, you can listen to this event in your render `controller`

```
$scope.$on('data-received', function(event, args) {
      $scope.m=share.get();
});
```

controller-1

```
app.controller("teacher",function($rootScope,$scope,$http,$location,$window,share){
    $scope.send = function(id){
      console.log(id);
      $http.get("/code/"+id).success(function(data){
        share.set(data);
        $rootScope.$broadcast('data-received');
        $window.location.href ='/code';
      })
    }
  });
```

controller-2

```
app.controller('render',function($rootScope,$scope,share){
    $scope.renders = function(){
      $scope.m=share.get();
      console.log($scope.m);
      }

      $scope.$on('data-received', function(event, args) {
        $scope.m=share.get();
      });
    });
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: @Ritik Saxena, pls check this answer.

Comment: It didn't work, the console.log($scope.m) returns an empty object, and I guess the $scope.$on is not getting called. I put a statement inside it which did not execute